# How can I draw an image like this text 3D and colors?

Tags: text-object

How can I draw an image like this text 3D and colors ?

[image: text3d and colors]

Comment: I guess that drawing really all that detail in 3d geometry is just too much... you could try something like this http://www.text-image.com/samples/face.html then apply something like this https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/84129/is-there-a-way-to-add-fake-thickness-to-an-alpha-image-texture/84618#84618... on a curved surface... just guessing...