# Solidify modifier: have a rim material that takes account of alpha

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, modifiers, image

I'm playing with sprites within Blender.
My goal is to display a 2D animation in a 3D world, and to give thickness to my drawings.

The thing that I would like to achieve is to give thickness to my drawings (using the Solidify modifier) depending of the drawings alpha.
Actually, I'm able to give my mesh thickness and to assign a different texture to the rim, but...  It doesn't give the drawing a rim, it gives its "container" a rim.

How could I do ?

[image]

Here's my actual process:

- Load my image using the 'Import Images as planes' addon
- Give that plane a material that displays the drawing; but is transparent depending of the alpha channel of the drawing.
- Add a Solidify modifier on the generated plane.
- In the Solidify modifier, assign another material using the "Material Index Offset"

How could I achieve this ?
Thanks !

Comment: Solidify modifier can't follow alpha. But you can fake it as in this question: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/84129/is-there-a-way-to-add-fake-thickness-to-an-alpha-image-texture

Comment: It's possible to use alpha to modulate a solidify (via a vertex weight edit modifier) but that's not really what you want.  Check out https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/84129/is-there-a-way-to-add-fake-thickness-to-an-alpha-image-texture for an example of what you want.  But what you should do is just cut your plane into appropriate shapes for your drawings.

Comment: The thing is that I want to use animated textures; so I can afford animate the mesh by hand...