# How do I pixelize this light screen?

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine

I am trying to recreate Wheatly from Portal, and I have tried to make his pixelated eyes by have a pixel grid with rectangular holes over the light source. However, as you can see by the picture, the curves within some of the pixels destroys the pixelated attempt. Is there a clear way for pixelating circuluar patterns like this? If, so, which method would you recommend? Thanks!
[image]

Comment: Have a look at the 'pixellate' node group from @Rich Sedman 's answer to [this question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/112304/how-to-achieve-a-realistic-material-for-an-operative-phone-screen/118394#118394)

Comment: No, How does he do it?

Answer (score 2):

While I am not familiar with the subject in question, one way would be to use a custom image and use it as an emissive shader.

image used: http://orig14.deviantart.net/3961/f/2012/050/a/f/wheatley__s_eye_by_mycroftporthos-d4qarjf.png

Obviously you can find a better image (more pixelated) or make your own and use some filter in photo editors app like Photoshop, Affinity, Gimp or whichever you prefer.
Photoshop has a bunch of filter under the category Pixelate.
Affinity also has a filter under the Distort category called Pixelate and I'm sure Gimp also has one. 
[image]

Answer (score 1):

This isn't more of an answer than [this one](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/112304/how-to-achieve-a-realistic-material-for-an-operative-phone-screen/118394#118394) by @Rich Sedman, but I've taken the 'pixellate' section from it and made an adjustable node-group from it.

This is the node group:

[image]

How it works is explained in the original answer.

This is an example of its usage:

[image]

Inputs: Number of tiles in X,  Number of tiles in Y, The thickness of the borders between pixels as a fraction of 1 (the full UV dimension)

Outputs: The vector to plug into your image texture, and an 'In Border' value of 0 or 1, so you can decide what to do with the parts of the output between the tiles.

Example material:

[image]

I can't promise it's bombproof .. or necessarily the simplest group to do this.

[image]