# How to create a false depth effect

Tags: materials

I'm looking for help. I'm trying to figure out if it's possible to create "3D" materials in Blender (preferably Eevee). What I mean is that such a material should be able to show features which are offset from the face normals, creating a 3D effect whilst being completely 2D. This is something which is done very well in (my alltime favourite) game, Destiny 2. I think the animation on **[this page](https://www.artstation.com/artwork/Xw0PD)** should give you an idea of what I'm talking about! It's mostly used for creating crystals, but also they have large stand-up displays in the game which have the same effect, where moving around the display you can see that the elements on the display are 'deep', giving a similar 3D effect.

I am not even sure where to begin with this. My understanding of materials is decent, but after playing around I haven't been able to find anything. Help would be appreciated!

Comment: I think one good avenue for you might be to search on 'parallax mapping'.  [This](https://www.artstation.com/loftus/blog/9B67/parallax-mapping-in-blender-part-1), for example, is a nice page 1.. I wish there was a page 2 in the same style, but there are plenty of other references.

Comment: Here’s a related example of parallax fake depth https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/84618/29586 . It’s different to your crystal example but similar principles apply. Also see https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/118394/29586 for use of parallax fake depth.

Comment: Thank you both, excellent resources! I will experiment with those, I guess I had forgotten that Blender's vectors *may* actually be matrices in disguise and therefore need multiplying together, not adding.