# Png issue extruding or adding geometry depth

Tags: geometry, extrude

I am new to Blender and I am trying to create a 3d image of a png in blender. Its quite a complex image and the knife tool wont work as there is too much detail. It just requires a minimal extrude or thickness in the geometry for the image.

I have looked everywhere for a lecture or tutorial but cant seem to find one that doesnt require the knife tool.

Comment: maybe check this answer: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/84129/is-there-a-way-to-add-fake-thickness-to-an-alpha-image-texture/84618#84618 ... or import your image, convert it to mesh, extrude the mesh?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.