# How do I duplicate a plane with an image+alpha to fake thickness?

Tags: modeling, modifiers

I'm struggling with the array modifier. It works fine duplicating the plane sideways but not in depth. Does nothing...
So what I'm trying to do:
I have a bunch of images that needs to go into the scene (as signs) but I just want to duplicate them 3 or 4 times to fake a bit of depth... but without creating the matrix like in this example: [Is there a way to add fake thickness to an alpha image texture?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/84129/is-there-a-way-to-add-fake-thickness-to-an-alpha-image-texture/84618#84618)

I have many of these so hoping there's a simple way to do this? Array seems like the winner but for some reason it's not working in the Y-axis... only Z and X (sideways, up-down)

Comment: It is probably not working because if you use the Relative Offset option for a flat object, the iterations will stick to the original, instead use the Constant Offset option and find the good value? If this is not the problem, please share your file

Comment: Thanks, I've tried that already, doesn't make a difference. I'll set up a simplified scene and upload in a bit

Comment: See [How to upload an image to a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [GIF](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963) File [blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com)