# Apply hole pattern to mesh

Tags: mesh

I'm looking to apply hole pattern to make this shoes. I've look up methods to create hole pattern but normally it'd be used to create something as simple as a cylinder (gun) or a ball (karaoke mic).
So i wonder if there is any way to create the hole pattern for (a more rather) complicated mesh like in the photo.
Thanks!

[image]
[image]

Here are a scrshot of what i'm working on

Comment: there could be some way, using booleans, but it would require some more regular base mesh topology, I fear. I tried with cylinders and works, but that shape above has far less regular topology...

Comment: With these jobs I leave the topology alone and insert an array of 'masked' holes instead.  These are parented to a common empty when the sandal is to be moved about.  Note that the holes even have depth.  OpenGL rendering is the only way to do this as far as I can tell.  Cycles might be able to.  mp4 link - if asked to sign in, just click on a vacant space -  
https://www.dropbox.com/s/czk8rte75yjz2h3/Sandal.mp4?dl=0

Comment: Related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/87384/add-repeating-pattern-to-surface

Answer (score 1):

Here is just an example about doing something like that with booleans, as I stated in my comment above...

starting form a shape like this:

[image]

and then from a copy object, using a cylinder as duplivert (faces), later converted to real object, like this:

[image]

then using booleans to subtract the second from the first, to obtain this:

[image]

As said, this would require some more regular base mesh topology, and could not be applicable to your model, at least as it is now, but could give you some inspiration to find a setup that works...