# Hole Cutting Topology

Tags: modeling, topology

Another hole cutting question. I think what I really don't understand about modelling is the topology.

I created following body using cylinder and already cut one screw hole on one of 
the sides. But I'm not happy with the topology used as it created n-gons. mesh is smooth and I don't see any artefacts. I also need to cut two more holes this way. This is tedious and looking for better way to model this.

[image]

[image]

finally, how do I go about something like this? cutting hole pattern, that is not even around axis.

[image]

Comment: you don't need so many vertices for your hole, 8 vertices are enough. About the last picture, I guess you can first model the hexa grid, then extrude the border and make it a circle

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/40997/how-can-i-make-a-hexagonal-grill/78003#78003 https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/58811/how-to-create-a-circular-shaped-grid-similar-to-a-manhole-cover

Comment: Thanks, guys. @moonboots can you please illustrate how you go about this?

Comment: Just did this in another thread: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/146003/creating-a-hole-out-of-an-custom-shape/146006#146006