# How to make custom grid

Tags: modeling, modifiers, add-on

I have this custom face and on that i want to make grid but not with the cylinder punch the hole. That will make more verts and faces and can disturb geometry. Anyway or addon can make a grid on my custom faces.

[image]

Comment: To clarify, you want to punch a grid of holes (the red ones), into your mesh, right?

Comment: @person132 need grids on that face without punching hole. The grid should be separate but should be similar to that face. Any grid shape (diamond, honeycomb, etc)

Comment: ok i posted an answer, hopefully that is what you were looking for.

Comment: Something like: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/40997/how-can-i-make-a-hexagonal-grill ?

Comment: @brockmann yes that what i needed, similar grid, but how can i make fit in my custom shape.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by custom shape. Please edit you question according to: https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @brockmann for example if i have circle shape and i want to fit that grid in that shape, or a above shape in my question its rectangle and a 2 loop cut at center and the center edge is pull. How can the grid fit in that shape. Like illustrator clipping mask or coreldraw powerclip, is there any option or way to fit that gird inside the face.

Comment: ... Please edit your question according to https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @brockmann i have posted my answer in the question plz have a look

Comment: @atek please write the answer in the answers section, not as part of the original question.

Comment: @susu i cannot write answer some one has mark the question to close. and 4 negative to the question.

Answer (score 3):

Making a grid of holes.

**1. start with some random shape**
[image: shape]

**2. Make a hole object:**

Make sure it goes all the way through your shape and is the size you want your holes to be.

[image: cylinder]

**3. Give it 2 array modifiers to make a 2d grid of cylinders:**

[image: grid]

Adjust the values to control how far apart the holes are

4. Add a boolean on the base object with the cylinder as the target, set to difference:

[image: boolean]

5. Hide the cylinder object:

[image: holes]

Now you have a bunch of holes, and the original geometry isnt changed. You can use the same method to make holes of basically any shape with a different mesh arrayed across.

Comment: As i have mention above not with the cylinder punching hole

Comment: i dont understand what you want, then. try to put a more detailed description in the question

Comment: i was looking for this way https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zg477W2oPyg

Comment: What you're showing is an addon, you can't do this kind of custom grid without an addon, I think person132 has shown you the best way to do it without any addon, because you can change the shape of the hole whenever you want

Comment: If you think that's the best way without any add-on, consider to upvote the answer @moonboots

Comment: sure, I was waiting an answer from Atek as his question is not clear enough in my opinion

Comment: I have posted my answer in the question have a look