# Mesoporous silica_tunneling structures

Tags: materials

I am working with mesoporous silica, a material based on tubular voids or rod-like internal spaces, where different molecules can be loaded.
I managed to do this in 2D, but I would like to "jump" to the 3D

Any idea how shall I proceed?

Thank you in advance

[image]

Comment: Hello :). Are you asking how to model such object in Blender? Should be fairly simple, where exactly are you stuck?

Comment: Hello @JachymMichal, I am a beginner in Blender, I would appreciate any kind of guidance

Comment: related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/40997/how-can-i-make-a-hexagonal-grill

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create a 6 vertex circle, right click and subdivide (all the parameters are in the *Operator* box on the bottom left of your 3D view):

[image]

Extrude inwards (press <kbd>E</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd> then Scale with <kbd>S</kbd>) and make the edge loop a circle with the *LoopTools* addon (activate the addon and right click > *LoopTools > Circle*):

[image]

Activate the *Auto Merge* and *Snap to Vertex* options, duplicate your mesh and stick the duplications:

[image]

[image]

Extrude downwards (<kbd>E</kbd> and move the selection along the normals), in *Object* mode right click > *Shade Smooth* and in the *Object Data* panel > *Normals*, enable the *Auto Smooth* option:

[image]

Comment: +1 ...and i thought that were half spheres looking out of the mesh....‍♂️ but he has 7 holes...yours just 3 ;)

Comment: "half spheres looking out of the mesh", what do you mean?

Comment: i meant like that: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fOe2d.png

Comment: oh yes I was also wondering but it looked like holes to me, I've just checked

Comment: I have one question, I managed to draw the hexagon but I have no idea how to "extrude inwards" in the second step. Thanks again

Comment: you need to press E and Enter, then S to scale

Comment: Great, thanks a lot!

Comment: @moonboots, Could you a bit more in detail the Auto merge part?

Comment: @  Edu39, I've edited my answer to show where you'll find the Auto Merge option (top right of your 3D View), it will allow you to automatically merge the vertices when they will snap (you can enable the Snap option (magnet icon) or press Ctrl to automatically snap, make sure that yoiu have selected Snap to Vertex in the dropdown menu on the right of the magnet icon)